# Built-in equivalent of RxSwift Variable or BehaviorRelay for RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-swift

**Question**

What's the best equivalent of `Variable` (deprecated already) or `BehaviorRelay` from RxSwift for RxJava?

**Addition**

In this case I assume that I could use `BehaviorSubject` which is built-in object in RxJava, but is it behaving identically to the objects mentioned above?

I also know that there is external library RxRelay, but is this the only option?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the subject and the relay is that the subject will record an error or completion, passing it downstream, while the relay only passes emissions.

The extension library from Jake Wharton implements the `BehaviorRelay` behavior, and it is equivalent to the RxSwift `BehaviorRelay`. You should have no problems using that extension library.

I'm not sure what your concern is about non-builtin functionality. The source code for the extension library is readily available and allows you to review the code before deploying it.